# Пунктуация и число сказуемого

Tags: пунктуация

"Возможность, а в отдельных случаях и необходимость использования в сфере юридической практики как логических, так и внелогических методов и приемов не вызывает сомнения".
Правильно ли стоит лишь одна запятая и сказуемое в ед. числе?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, в Вашем предложении запятых две. Я бы добавила еще одну, закрыв вставную конструкцию *а в отдельных случаях и необходимость*.

Запятые при однородных членах расставлены верно. Здесь два ряда однородных членов. ПРи составном союзе запятая ставится перед второй частью союза (как..., так и). Перед одиночным союзом И запятая не ставится.

Грамматическая основа - возможность не вызывает сомнения, ед. число верно.

Answer (score 0):

Не соглашусь с Ларf насчет вставной конструкции. По-моему, *возможность* и *необходимость* в данном случае однородные подлежащие, соединенные союзом *а*. При этом запятая после *необходимость* не нужна, на мой взгляд, все знаки препинания верны. Приведу параграф из "Грамоты":

§ 144. Запятая ставится между однородными членами предложения, соединенными посредством союзов: а, но, да (в значении «но»), однако, хотя и т. п., например:

```
Не род, а ум поставлю в воеводы.
Пушкин

Она говорила мало, но толково.
Тургенев

На взгляд-то он хорош, да зелен.
Крылов

Неодолимая, хотя и тихая сила увлекала меня.
Тургенев
```

Число, думаю, можно употребить как множественное, так и единичное.

Comment: В исходном примере "а" не является противительным союзом. Примеры из "Грамоты" иллюстрируют совсем другую ситуацию.

Comment: Примеры из "Грамоты" иллюстрируют моменты, в которых можно спутать однородные чл. предложения с уточнением (вставной конструкцией).

Answer (score 0):

```
"Возможность, а в отдельных случаях и необходимость использования в сфере юридической практики как логических, так и внелогических методов и приемов не вызывает сомнения".
```

В этом предложении используется **ряд однородных членов** "возможность... необходимость" при одном главном слове "использования". Соединены эти однородные члены конструкцией "а в отдельных случаях и", которая, на мой взгляд, выполняет ту же функцию, что и **союз "не только, но и"** или обычный союз **И**. Ср.: Не только возможность, но и необходимость использования... Запятую после слова "необходимость" ставить не нужно. Противительных отношений здесь тоже, конечно же, нет.

Comment: "использования" не может быть главным словом, так как мы ставим вопрос не от него, а к нему: возможность и необходимость (чего?) использования. "Использования" просто общее, но зависимое от этих слов.